# ILIKE Operator on uuid v4 type column with Sequelize Cast

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to run ILIKE operator on uuid type column in postgres v10. Something like this,

```
select * from users where id ILIKE '%0%';
```

but as we both know, this does not work. So I tried casting it to `varchar` and tried again with query something like this.

```
select * from workspace_columns where id::varchar ILIKE '%0%';
```

and voila it worked. Now I have to perform something similar with Sequelize (ORM for node js). I found solutions but they all are talking with sequelize.cast function, which I cannot use as my current code is using params method. Something like this:-

```
model.findAndCountAll(params || {})
```

where params is a js object.

Is there someway I could pass the information that i want to cast this column before doing ILike?

Maybe something like this:-

```
{ where : { Sequelize.cast('name', 'varchar'): { [Sequelize.Op.iLike] : '%w%'} } }
```

Comment: `LIKE` on a UUID value does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know but let's say I have a scenerio

Answer (score 1):

you could try using raw sql

```
sequelize.query("select * from workspace_columns where id::varchar ILIKE :search_name",{ replacements: { search_name: 'ben%'  }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,model: Projects,mapToModel: true  }).then(projects => {console.log(projects)}
```

Comment: raw query is the path I would not prefer